# List of files between two timestamps

Tags: file, batch-file

using the below code we are able to list the files between two dates.
But we need to check the timestamp also. i.e. List all the files between date & time.

```
wmic datafile where "drive='%drive%' and path='%folder:\=\\%' and creationdate>'%start%' and creationdate<'%end%'" get creationdate, name, size
```

Comment: wmic will be pretty slow...

Comment: @npocmaka - WMIC DATAFILE performance isn't so bad as long as drive and full path are specified.

Answer (score 1):

Check [FileTimeFilterJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/FileTimeFilterJS.bat)
To print files between two dates in the current directory try with in :

```
call FileTimeFilterJS "." -beginDate "September 1, 2014 10:15 AM" -endDate "November 1, 2014 10:15 PM"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not working for me. Any other solution .@echo off


setlocal 
set "drive=%~d1"
set "folder=%~pnx1\"
set /a "start=%~2, end=%~3" 
wmic datafile where "drive='%drive%' and path='%folder:\=\\%' and creationdate>'%start%' and creationdate<'%end%'" get creationdate, name, size
 I am using this command. It is working for dates not for Timestamp

Comment: @user4809060 - what do you mean with time stamp?

Comment: date+time 20150420210712 (YYYYMMDDHHmmss)

Comment: I have tried      find . -type f -newermt "2014-10-08 10:17:00" ! -newermt "2014-10-08 10:53:00". But it is also not working. Any quick help. Thanks

Comment: @user4809060 check also this https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/FileTimeFilerJS.bat  - it basically the same tool but uses `.NET` and the date format is more convenient.You can update it to use a file format that fits you

Answer (score 1):

Working with timestamps in WMI queries is a pain. You must either specify a date in the format `'YYYYMMDD'`, or date and time in the format `'YYYYMMDDhhmmss.ffffffSZZZ'`

Where

- `YYYY` = full four digit year
- `MM` = two digit month
- `DD` = two digit day of month
- `hh` = two digit hours in 24 hour format
- `mm` = two digit minutes
- `ss` = two digit seconds
- `.ffffff` = six digit fractional seconds (microseconds)
- `SZZZ` = time zone expressed as minutes offset from UTC time

  - `S` = time zone sign, either `+`, or `-`
  - `ZZZ` = three digit minutes

When expressing a date, the string must be exactly 6 characters long.
For example, January 15, 2015 is expressed as `'20150115'`.

When expressing a date-time, the string must be exactly 25 characters long. 
For example, January 15, 2015, 3:14 PM Eastern Standard Time is expressed as 
`'20150115151400.000000-300'`.

So your existing query does not have to change. You just need to make sure your `%start%` 
and `%end%` strings are properly formatted date-time values.

Comment: I tried using DateTime. But I got "invalid number. numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision" as the error.

Comment: Is there any other ways to list the files with out using WMI

Comment: @user4809060 - I don't know what to say. I used your exact code with properly formatted date-time values, and it worked perfectly. Did you use SET /A when you defined start and end? That will not work - you need to use a normal SET, as you are defining a string, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Another much simpler (and faster!) approach would be this one:

**EDIT**: I modified the former code so it now process creation dates, instead of last modified ones.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~2" neq "" goto begin
echo Usage: %0  YYYYMMDDHHMMstart  YYYYMMDDHHMMend
goto :EOF

:begin
for /F "skip=5 tokens=1-7* delims=/: " %%a in ('dir /A-D /T:C *.*') do (
   if "%%h" equ "" goto break
   set "hour=%%d"
   if "%%f" equ "p.m." set /A "hour=(1%%d+12)%%100"
   set "fileDate=%%c%%a%%b!hour!%%e"
   if "!fileDate!" geq "%~1" if "!fileDate!" leq "%~2" echo %%a/%%b/%%c  %%d:%%e %%f   %%g   %%h
)
:break
```

Yes, I know that this method don't include the seconds and it is locale dependant, but it may be enough for the OP and a certain number of users. The locale problem may be fixed with a simple change in the `%%c%%a%%b` order to the appropriate one (like `%%c%%b%%a`) and perhaps a small adjustment in the `"tokens=1-7*` part.