# How to Find Files within A Date Range

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I wanted to find the files that are created/modified from 7 days ago to today, `FORFILES /D +*7 days ago date*` output is what I want.
But I want the date to change automatically everyday instead of manually changing it.

I tried using powershell to get the date but cmd prompts me error.

```
SET dateRef=powershell.exe (get-date).AddDays(-7).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
forFiles /p <path here> /d +%dateRef%
```

Cmd prompts me this error `ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '(get-date).AddDays(-7).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')'.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of files between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742739/list-of-files-between-two-timestamps)

Comment: I don't think so wmic requires the hard coded date right? I want it to be able to change the date automatically everyday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output of a command using For /F

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`powershell.exe -command {& "(get-date).AddDays(-7).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')"}`) do set dateRef=%%a
forFiles /p <path here> /d +%dateRef%
```

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell you can get all files modified during the last 7 days :

```
Get-ChildItem | Where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
```

Should you need to create a list to use then in your batch file :

```
Get-ChildItem | Where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | Select -Expand FullName | Out-File list.txt
```